# Java wrapper around a PE (.exe)

Tags: java, c++, wrapper

Is there any way to make a Java program (in Windows) that just acts as a wrapper around a PE 
(.exe), passing all stdin input to the program and writing out to stdout everything that the PE writes out.

I need this because the interface for a program only allows Java classes, but I want it to run some code that I've put together in C++.

Thanks in advance.

edit: portability is 0% important. This only needs to work in Windows and will never be needed to work anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory("myDir");
 Process p = pb.start();
```

[and another example of it](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/8-using-the-new-process-builder-class.html).

Comment: Cool. I'll try that and get back to you (or tick this :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with java.lang.Runtime.ecec() and java.lang.Process with which you can acces all 3 streams(in/out/err) to the *.exe you are executing.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the standard Java mechanisms ([ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and its [ilk](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)). However, reliably re-routing stdout/stdin/errout requires [care](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) ([additional](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/exec.html#COMMUNICATING)). If you don't need to process this I/O inside your Java app, consider using a native call (e.g. C's [`system`](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html#stdlib.h) function) via [JNI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) ([demo here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369860/implementing-the-system-command-in-java/1370405#1370405)).