# How can I run a Ruby script from command line and get the response using Java code?

Tags: java, ruby, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I need to run the Ruby script using command line from Java code.

For example my file is in the path **D:/MyProject/myruby.rb**

I want to run this file from command line and get the response from that. How can I achieve this?

Also, how can we return the response in **myruby.rb** which could be caught in the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369860/implementing-the-system-command-in-java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String[] commands = {"ruby","D:/MyProject/myruby.rb"};

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process proc;
try
{
    proc = rt.exec(commands);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String s;

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: My Ruby file is in the Directory D:/MyProject. So where can specify the path

Comment: You should then specify the complete path in the String array String[] commands = {"ruby"," D:/MyProject/myruby.rb"};